# Rails model fields not updating to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### Models used

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :model,:edition
  attr_accessible :model,:edition  
  has_many :wheels
end

class Wheel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :type,:tubeless
  attr_accessible :type,:tubeless
  belongs_to :car
end
```

### Create operation

```
irb(main):009:0> bnz = Car.create :model=>"BENZ" , :edition=>2011
=> #<Car id: 5, model: nil, edition: nil, created_at: "2011-08-26 09:08:08", upd
ated_at: "2011-08-26 09:08:08">
```

**Problem:**
The above creates record successfully but my :model and :edition values are not sent to database. only id,created_at,updated_at values are getting created in database.

### Update operation

```
irb(main):010:0> fifth = Car.find(5)
irb(main):011:0> fifth.update_attributes(:edition=>2011, :model=>"BENZ")
=> true
irb(main):012:0> fifth.update_attributes!(:edition=>2011, :model=>"BENZ")
=> true
irb(main):013:0> fifth.update_attributes!(:edition=>2012, :model=>"BENZ")
=> true
irb(main):014:0>
```

**Problem:**
Nothing is happening here. In developement.log only select statements are fired, no update statement is fired

I'm using sqlite db. Using sqlite manager firefox addon to view the db tables.
New to rails, Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use `attr_accessor` as that is defining virtual attributes, overriding the setters uses for the fields. Remove those lines using it from your models and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks to you Ryan (Radar). works well. like to be a student to you ;-)